# Exigir login para acessar site wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tenho que fazer um portal, porem ele só pode ser acessado por gente autorizada, como faço isso com wordpress? sou bem iniciante e nao sei como proceder neste caso

Answer (score 1):

Opção direto dentro do Tema.

No `functions.php` do seu tema coloque esse código. Link do projeto no GitHub: https://github.com/kevinvess/wp-force-login

```
  $url  = isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && 'on' === $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http';
  $url .= '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
  $url .= in_array( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'], array('80', '443') ) ? '' : ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
  $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  return $url;
}
function v_forcelogin() {
  if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $url = v_getUrl();
    $whitelist = apply_filters('v_forcelogin_whitelist', array());
    $redirect_url = apply_filters('v_forcelogin_redirect', $url);
    if( preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $url) != preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', wp_login_url()) && !in_array($url, $whitelist) ) {
      wp_safe_redirect( wp_login_url( $redirect_url ), 302 ); exit();
    }
  }
}
add_action('init', 'v_forcelogin');
```

Se quiser usar o Plugin do snippet acima sugiro usar esse plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Outra opção de plugin é o **Restrict Content** (existe versão paga tem que ver se o free te atende): https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]